# Group by using Left Join in SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I have two tables, and I am trying to do a left join on Lockedlist.NR against PoReportTable.Tracking_Field in order to do a "group by" PoReportTable.COST However, I am stuck and not sure where I am going wrong.
In Excel I would have done a "sumif" formula, but using Pandas and SQL I am stuck...

Is anyone able to lend a hand?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("data_superstore.db")
query3=''' 
SELECT Lockedlist.NR,
Lockedlist.Programme,
PoReportTable.COST,
PoReportTable.Short_Text
FROM Lockedlist
LEFT JOIN PoReportTable
ON Lockedlist.NR= PoReportTable.Tracking_Field
GROUP BY PoReportTable.COST
ORDER BY PoReportTable.COST DESC;
'''
```

Sample output

```
NR  Programme   COST
73645   Road  231.34
42536   Space 345.24
42536   Space 145.11
10021   Tech 947.38
10021   Tech    681.18
10021   Tech 1751.71
```

Expected Result

```
NR  Programme   COST
42536 Space 490.35
10021 Tech 3380.27
73645 Road 231.45
```

Comment: Please include your error message

Comment: Hello @Bialomazur, I do not have an error message. I was looking for the logic in order to be able to sumif the PoReportTable.COST column

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @TheImpaler I will add an example now

Answer (score 1):

To produce the result you want you probably want to group by `NR`, not `COST`, and then sort by `total_cost` in a descending way. If that's the case you can do:

```
SELECT
  Lockedlist.NR,
  max(Lockedlist.Programme) as Programme,
  sum(PoReportTable.COST) as total_cost
FROM Lockedlist
LEFT JOIN PoReportTable ON Lockedlist.NR= PoReportTable.Tracking_Field
GROUP BY Lockedlist.NR
ORDER BY sum(PoReportTable.COST) DESC;
```